# How can I find out the version of a library that is packaged with Ruby, e.g. json?

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems, version

Some Ruby functionality packaged with the Ruby distribution (and not needing to be installed as gems explicitly or via bundler). JSON is one example (`require 'json'`). It can be required in Ruby code but doesn't require gem installation.

Yet JSON is a gem on Github, at https://github.com/flori/json.

So how can I know which version of that gem I'm getting when I require 'json' in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for solution that works even for gems or files that do not contain constant with version info:

```rb
require 'json'
$LOADED_FEATURES.select { |x| x.match? 'json' }
```

or

```rb
require 'json'
Gem.loaded_specs['json'].version
=> Gem::Version.new("2.6.1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively many ruby gems specify their version in a constant.

You can utilize this to determine the version you are using in code or in console as well e.g.

```
require 'json'
JSON.constants.grep(/VERSION/)
#=>[:VERSION, :VERSION_ARRAY, :VERSION_MAJOR, :VERSION_MINOR, :VERSION_BUILD]
JSON::VERSION
#=> 2.5.1
require 'bundler'
Bundler.constants.grep(/VERSION/)
#=> [:VERSION]
Bundler::VERSION
#=> 2.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Ruby home directory, and search below it for a directory of the appropriate name, and then inspect its `version.rb` file. For example, with rvm-managed rubies, I can do this (on a Posix-compliant system such as Linux or Mac OS):

```
$ cd $(which ruby)/../..; pwd
/Users/keith.bennett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1

$find . -type d -name '*json*'
./lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych/json
./lib/ruby/3.0.0/json
./lib/ruby/3.0.0/rdoc/generator/template/json_index
./lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-darwin19/json
./lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/json-2.5.1
./lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rbs-1.0.4/stdlib/json
```

I can `cat ./lib/ruby/3.0.0/json/version.rb | grep 'VERSION '` (include the space after "VERSION"), and I get:

```
  VERSION         = '2.5.1'
```

..which is also the version of the gem in the `gems` directory included in the listing above.

So I can see that 2.5.1 is my JSON version.