# Chef Recipe - check if kernel version is at a certain level or greater

Tags: kernel, chef-infra, version

I have a line in my recipe which needs to run if the client is at a certain kernel version or greater.  ie:

```
if platform_family?('rhel') && node['platform_version'].to_i == 5 && node['kernel']['release'].to_f >= 2.6.33
```

I'm not sure how to check the kernel.release.  The .to_f isn't correct, since it's not really a float.  So, my cookstyle check fails.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68040422/how-can-i-find-out-the-version-of-a-library-that-is-packaged-with-ruby-e-g-jso) which does something similar with versioning, but not sure if that is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

We will need extended functionality such as [mixlib-versioning](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-versioning) over Ruby's native Integer or Float data types to parse and compare semantic versions.

Also, `node['kernel']['release']` has other bits of identification, such as OS distribuation, CPU architecture, etc. We can use `node['packages']['kernel']['version']` instead to get only the semantic version, like 2.6.33. This will be easier to compare.

So, if we have a recipe such as below, we will have the ability to compare versions:

```rb
chef_gem 'mixlib-versioning' do
  compile_time true
  action :install
end

require 'mixlib/versioning'

kernel_version = Mixlib::Versioning.parse(node['packages']['kernel']['version'])
req_version = Mixlib::Versioning.parse('2.6.33')

# Then use these for comparison
if kernel_version >= req_version
  # Do something
end
```

Comment: This was useful, however it only seems to return a value for CentOS/RH, which may be enough for what I need.   The only options I seem to have for Ubuntu to get kernel info are  node['kernel']['release'] and node['hostnamectl']['kernel']